# Oracle SQL Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to writing PL/SQL Code to do Triggers.

I have a Book database that has columns [Title, Author, Score, Votes, Year].

When I insert a new book into the database, I want to set a book that has no Year information to 2014 and add `_changed` to the end of the title.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER book_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON BOOK
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.YR IS NULL THEN :NEW.YR := 2014;
IF :NEW.YR IS NULL THEN :NEW.TITLE := :OLD.TITLE + '_changed'
END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

My issue is the title not adding `_changed` to it.

Comment: Change your + to || (Oracle concatenation operator)

Comment: I changed it to `IF :NEW.YR IS NULL THEN :NEW.TITLE := :OLD.TITLE || '_changed'` but that did not add `_changed` to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want to change an inserted record to have "_changed" appended, you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER book_trigger
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON BOOK
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.YR IS NULL 
    THEN 
        :NEW.YR := 2014;
        :NEW.TITLE := :OLD.TITLE || '_changed';
    end if;
END;
/
```

As suggested by @agent5566, you might consider not doing that for inserts, and only doing it on update.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize you could have multiple changes within one `If Then` for Triggers.

Comment: It is very odd to work with `:OLD.TITLE` on `INSERT` @Together_United

Comment: If the trigger were only for INSERT, then you could just set :NEW.TITLE := '_changed' (which is odd, but is apparently the requirement.  But since the trigger is for UPDATE as well, it makes sense to leave :OLD.TITLE in there.

Comment: I meant to use `NEW.TITLE := :NEW.TITLE || '_changed'` I was wanting to do everything on insert, which I stated above however my code was wrong @agent5566

Answer (score 2):

First of all your second `if` condition will never be `TRUE`, because you set `:NEW.YR` just line before. Second your trigger fires on `BEFORE INSERT` and `:OLD.TITLE` will be always `NULL`.I can only suggest that you want something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER book_trigger
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON BOOK
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.YR IS NULL 
    THEN 
        :NEW.YR := 2014;
    END IF;
    if updating then
        :NEW.TITLE := :OLD.TITLE || '_changed';
    end if;
END;
```

Note `updating` flag, it predefined by oracle, it tell us that row is updating now, not inserting and we can work with `:OLD` only in `UPDATING` mode.

Comment: Are you suggesting to change the code to: `IF :NEW.YR IS NULL THEN :NEW.YR := 2014;
END IF;
IF :NEW.YR IS NULL THEN :NEW.TITLE := :NEW.TITLE || '_new';
END IF;` Because I have tried that, I understand now why the second `if`statement would never be `True`

Comment: @Together_United May be so, it depends on business logic

Comment: I am wanting to do both of these events when inserting a record, not updating. That is why I am stuck. I am not sure how to make that second `IF :NEW.YEAR IS NULL` become `TRUE`

Comment: You can't have a '+' in there.  You'll get a numeric value error.